# In Vuetify, how to add a button into each row in <v-data-table>?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The screenshot belwo is an example in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/
[image]
And its code is:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

I am wondering how to add a `<v-btn>` into each row to navigate to another component?

Like, adding a column which contains buttons called "view" in each row, and clicking on them will navigate to the page containing the details of the corresponding dessert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a header called `action`.

```js
  { text: "", value: "action" }
```

And then specify the rendering of this header with a `slot`.

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts">
  <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
    <v-btn>OPEN</v-btn>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#simple-checkbox

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need. Could you please tell me what do the 2 brackets in ```{ item }``` mean? Does it equal to ```item.item```?

Comment: This is the destructuration of the slot's parameter : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props